# Manipulation Container not working in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to restrict the image movement placed inside a canvas on touch manipulation while translating, rotating and scaling(pinch to zoom).
I tried to implement manipulationcontainer property but it didn't give me the desired results.
Any help is appreciated!!!

XAMl Code-

```
<Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Grid.Column="1"> 
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="imgBg" ImageSource="/Images/Backgrounds/bg0.jpg"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
                <Image x:Name="imgTest" Source="/Images/Sample.jpg" ManipulationStarted="image_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="image_OnManipulationDelta" Height="150" Width="190" Canvas.Top="80" Margin="12,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
                <Image x:Name="imgTest2" Source="/Images/Sample2.jpg" ManipulationStarted="image_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="image_OnManipulationDelta" Height="150" Width="190" Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="200" Margin="12,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
                <Image x:Name="imgTest3" Source="/Images/Sample3.jpg" ManipulationStarted="image_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="image_OnManipulationDelta" Height="150" Width="190" Canvas.Top="240" Margin="12,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
                <Image x:Name="imgTest4" Source="/Images/Sample4.jpg" ManipulationStarted="image_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="image_OnManipulationDelta" Height="150" Width="190" Canvas.Top="240" Canvas.Left="200" Margin="12,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </Canvas>
```

C# Code-

```
double _scaleX, _scaleY, _translationX, _translationY;

private void image_OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            // the user has started manipulating the screen, set starting points
            var transform = (CompositeTransform)((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(sender)).RenderTransform;
            _scaleX = transform.ScaleX;
            _scaleY = transform.ScaleY;
            _translationX = transform.TranslateX;
            _translationY = transform.TranslateY;

            e.ManipulationContainer = mainCanvas;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

private void image_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            var transform = (CompositeTransform)((FrameworkElement)(sender)).RenderTransform;
            Image imgSender = sender as Image;
            // pan
            transform.TranslateX = _translationX + e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X;
            transform.TranslateY = _translationY + e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y;           

            if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
            {
                // zoom
                transform.CenterX = e.PinchManipulation.Original.Center.X;
                transform.CenterY = e.PinchManipulation.Original.Center.Y;

                transform.ScaleX = _scaleX * e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;
                transform.ScaleY = _scaleY * e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;

                //rotate
                transform.Rotation = angleBetween2Lines(e.PinchManipulation.Current, e.PinchManipulation.Original);
            }

            Point p = new Point(0, 0);

            Rect containingRect = new Rect(p,((FrameworkElement)e.ManipulationContainer).RenderSize);

            Rect shapeBounds = imgSender.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(p,imgSender.RenderSize));

            Point bound = new Point(shapeBounds.Top, shapeBounds.Bottom);

            if (e.IsInertial && !containingRect.Contains(bound))
            {
                e.Complete();
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the parent canvas as a child of ScrollViewer worked for me.